# Python module to extract probable dates from strings?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python module that would take an arbitrary block of text, search it for something that looks like a date string, and build a DateTime object out of it.  Something like [Date::Extract](http://search.cpan.org/~sartak/Date-Extract-0.03/lib/Date/Extract.pm) in Perl

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nearest equivalent is probably the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module.  Usage is:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("Wed, Nov 12")
datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 12, 0, 0)
```

Using the fuzzy parameter should ignore extraneous text.  ie

```
>>> parse("the date was the 1st of December 2006 2:30pm", fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2006, 12, 1, 14, 30)
```

Comment: This is better than parsedatetime, but the input string can only have a single date in it.

Answer (score 5):

Why no give [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) a try?

Comment: I took a look at this. On their todo: "Ability to scan large parts of text and extract any found date/time information". That kind of rules it out for me.